# where to find the previous definition of #define value

Tags: command-line, c-preprocessor, caffe

I have made a mistake to change the .h file for some reason. And I do the `#define CPU_ONLY 1` in the file, but I forgot its name.

Now I come across this problem when I make caffe test in terminal

```
./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:4:9: warning: 'CPU_ONLY' macro
  redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define CPU_ONLY
    ^
<command line>:6:9: note: previous definition is here
#define CPU_ONLY 1
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

How can I find the .h file I had changed, and I have searched in finder on MAC OS yet.

Comment: it is defined by the makefile in the input arguments for the compiler,

Comment: Oh, I remember that I changed the device_alternate.hpp by adding `#define CPU_ONLY` instead of `#define CPU_ONLY 1` in some .h file. After delete it in .hpp file, the warning gone. Thank you~@Shai